# org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to setup Solr 4.3.1 with a Wordpress database running on MySQL 5.6

But on trying a full import:
`http://localhost:8983/solr/tv-wordpress/dataimport?command=full-import&debug=true`

The error is:
`org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish'`

I executed the statement in MySQL Workbench 6.06 and there it works.

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306/wptalkman" user="root" password="****" />
    <document name="articles">
        <entity pk="id" name="article" query="SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish';">     
            <field name="id" column="ID" />
            <field name="post_title" column="post_title" />
            <field name="post_author" column="post_author" />           
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I also tried including the database name in the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish';
```

and change the connection url to `jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306`

Also tried adding logtransformer:

```
    <entity pk="ID" name="article" query="SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish'" 
            transformer="LogTransformer" logTemplate="The name is ${e.name}" logLevel="debug" >
```

**console output**

```
13420 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimpleProperties 
Writer  û Read dataimport.properties 
13506 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource 
û Creating a connection for entity article with URL: jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306/w 
ptalkman 
13510 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource 
û Time taken for getConnection(): 4 
13510 [qtp16103450-12] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  û Ex 
ception while processing: article document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr 
.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT 
* FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' Processing Document # 1 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAnd 
Throw(DataImportHandlerException.java:71) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.< 
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou 
rce.java:210) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou 
rce.java:38) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEn 
tityProcessor.java:59) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEnti 
tyProcessor.java:73) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(Ent 
ityProcessorWrapper.java:243) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde 
r.java:465) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde 
r.java:404) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.j 
ava:319) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java 
:227) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImpo 
rter.java:422) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.j 
ava:487) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBod 
y(DataImportHandler.java:179) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl 
erBase.java:135) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1820) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter 
.java:656) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte 
r.java:359) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte 
r.java:155) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet 
Handler.java:1307) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java 
:453) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j 
ava:137) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav 
a:560) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl 
er.java:231) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl 
er.java:1072) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java: 
382) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle 
r.java:193) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle 
r.java:1006) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j 
ava:135) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont 
extHandlerCollection.java:255) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl 
ection.java:154) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper 
.java:116) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(Abstrac 
tHttpConnection.java:485) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(Blockin 
gHttpConnection.java:53) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(Abstra 
ctHttpConnection.java:926) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.header 
Complete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) 

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpCo 
nnection.java:72) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(So 
cketConnector.java:264) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo 
l.java:608) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool 
.java:543) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.< 
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241) 
        ... 42 more 

13546 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor 
  û [tv-wordpress] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import&deb 
ug=true} {} 0 150 
13546 [qtp16103450-12] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  û 
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.a 
pache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute quer 
y: SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' Processing Docum 
ent # 1 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java 
:266) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImpo 
rter.java:422) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.j 
ava:487) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBod 
y(DataImportHandler.java:179) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl 
erBase.java:135) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1820) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter 
.java:656) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte 
r.java:359) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte 
r.java:155) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet 
Handler.java:1307) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java 
:453) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j 
ava:137) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav 
a:560) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl 
er.java:231) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl 
er.java:1072) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java: 
382) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle 
r.java:193) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle 
r.java:1006) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j 
ava:135) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont 
extHandlerCollection.java:255) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl 
ection.java:154) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper 
.java:116) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(Abstrac 
tHttpConnection.java:485) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(Blockin 
gHttpConnection.java:53) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(Abstra 
ctHttpConnection.java:926) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.header 
Complete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) 

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpCo 
nnection.java:72) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(So 
cketConnector.java:264) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo 
l.java:608) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool 
.java:543) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataIm 
portHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts 
WHERE post_status='publish' Processing Document # 1 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde 
r.java:406) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.j 
ava:319) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java 
:227) 
        ... 33 more 
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable 
 to execute query: SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' 
Processing Document # 1 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAnd 
Throw(DataImportHandlerException.java:71) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.< 
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou 
rce.java:210) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou 
rce.java:38) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEn 
tityProcessor.java:59) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEnti 
tyProcessor.java:73) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(Ent 
ityProcessorWrapper.java:243) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde 
r.java:465) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde 
r.java:404) 
        ... 35 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.< 
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241) 
        ... 42 more 

13568 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  û start rollb 
ack{} 
13569 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState  û Crea 
ting new IndexWriter... 
13569 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState  û Wait 
ing until IndexWriter is unused... core=tv-wordpress 
13589 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û SolrDeletionPolicy 
.onInit: commits:num=1 
        commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory 
@C:\Dropbox\Databases\solr-4.3.1\example\example-DIH\solr\tv-wordpress\data\inde 
x lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.SingleInstanceLockFactory@13396fa; maxCach 
eMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_3l,generation=129,filenames=[_3o.nvd 
, _3o_Lucene41_0.tim, _3o.fnm, _3o.nvm, _3o_Lucene41_0.tip, _3o.fdt, _3o_Lucene4 
1_0.pos, segments_3l, _3o.fdx, _3o_Lucene41_0.doc, _3o.si] 
13590 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û newest commit = 12 
9[_3o.nvd, _3o_Lucene41_0.tim, _3o.fnm, _3o.nvm, _3o_Lucene41_0.tip, _3o.fdt, _3 
o_Lucene41_0.pos, segments_3l, _3o.fdx, _3o_Lucene41_0.doc, _3o.si] 
13591 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState  û New 
IndexWriter is ready to be used. 
13591 [qtp16103450-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  û end_rollbac 
k
```

**update: added logger in JDBC connection string**

With this URL `url="jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306/wptalkman?logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log4JLogger&profileSQL=true;"`

I get:
`Data Config problem: The reference to entity "profileSQL" must end with the ';' delimiter.`

with this url: `url="jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306/wptalkman?logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log4JLogger"`

I get this in console:

```
5696 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource  û
 Creating a connection for entity article with URL: jdbc:mysql@localhost:3306/wp
talkman?logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log4JLogger
5700 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource  û
 Time taken for getConnection(): 4
5700 [qtp16103450-11] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder  û Exc
eption while processing: article document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.
handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT *
 FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAnd
Throw(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou
rce.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou
rce.java:38)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEn
tityProcessor.java:59)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEnti
tyProcessor.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(Ent
ityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde
r.java:465)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde
r.java:404)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.j
ava:319)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java
:227)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImpo
rter.java:422)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.j
ava:487)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBod
y(DataImportHandler.java:179)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl
erBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1820)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter
.java:656)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:359)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java
:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl
er.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
er.java:1072)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:
382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle
r.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
r.java:1006)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont
extHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl
ection.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(Abstrac
tHttpConnection.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(Blockin
gHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(Abstra
ctHttpConnection.java:926)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.header
Complete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpCo
nnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(So
cketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo
l.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool
.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241)
        ... 42 more

5714 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor
 û [tv-wordpress] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import&debu
g=true} {} 0 122
5715 [qtp16103450-11] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  û F
ull Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.ap
ache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query
: SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' Processing Docume
nt # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java
:266)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImpo
rter.java:422)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.j
ava:487)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBod
y(DataImportHandler.java:179)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl
erBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1820)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter
.java:656)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:359)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java
:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl
er.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
er.java:1072)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:
382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle
r.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
r.java:1006)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont
extHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl
ection.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(Abstrac
tHttpConnection.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(Blockin
gHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(Abstra
ctHttpConnection.java:926)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.header
Complete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpCo
nnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(So
cketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo
l.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool
.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataIm
portHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts
WHERE post_status='publish' Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde
r.java:406)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.j
ava:319)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java
:227)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable
 to execute query: SELECT * FROM wptalkman.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish'
Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAnd
Throw(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou
rce.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSou
rce.java:38)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEn
tityProcessor.java:59)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEnti
tyProcessor.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(Ent
ityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde
r.java:465)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilde
r.java:404)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<
init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241)
        ... 42 more

5737 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  û start rollba
ck{}
5738 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState  û Creat
ing new IndexWriter...
5739 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState  û Waiti
ng until IndexWriter is unused... core=tv-wordpress
5776 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û SolrDeletionPolicy.
onInit: commits:num=1
        commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory
@C:\Dropbox\Databases\solr-4.3.1\example\example-DIH\solr\tv-wordpress\data\inde
x lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.SingleInstanceLockFactory@1a1a366; maxCach
eMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_3l,generation=129,filenames=[_3o.nvd
, _3o_Lucene41_0.tim, _3o.fnm, _3o.nvm, _3o_Lucene41_0.tip, _3o.fdt, _3o_Lucene4
1_0.pos, segments_3l, _3o.fdx, _3o_Lucene41_0.doc, _3o.si]
5777 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û newest commit = 129
[_3o.nvd, _3o_Lucene41_0.tim, _3o.fnm, _3o.nvm, _3o_Lucene41_0.tip, _3o.fdt, _3o
_Lucene41_0.pos, segments_3l, _3o.fdx, _3o_Lucene41_0.doc, _3o.si]
5777 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState  û New I
ndexWriter is ready to be used.
5778 [qtp16103450-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  û end_rollback
```

Comment: Connect to your mysql directly and run your select * from wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' and see if it has any data and make sure it has ID, post_title and post_author as columns to start with.

Comment: I tried running the statement from both MySQL Workbench and console and there the statement executes successfully (had to make the reserved words uppercase though will change that in my post). But still the same error occurs.

Comment: Can you log the JDBC connection to get more detail on what's going on? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13025521/816584

Comment: @SteveBuzonas: Thanks. I updated my post with logging enabled, but it does not seem to show anything new?

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? Then we could look up the source of the NullPointerException.

Comment: It is failing [in line 241](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_3/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/JdbcDataSource.java#L241), so the connection is null. Did you double check the JDBC string?

Comment: @cheffe: yes, but by simply changing the JDBC string in the data-config.xml: tried leaving out the portnumber, the database name, but I keep getting the same error. What is the best way to check if my URL is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jdbc-connection-string-mysql-postgresql-sqlserver (see bottom of page)

Turns out instead of `@` in my connection string I had to use `://`
Now it works :)