# Java: how to print the rows from database?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have this program:

```
class DataRetrieve {

    DataRetrieve() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phonebook", "root", "1234");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select * from contacts");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataRetrieve dr = new DataRetrieve();
        //here i want to print that table rows into Console using this
        System.out.println(); // How do you print here that table rows?
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how to print this database information in `System.out.println`?

Comment: You'll probably want to start with some introductory Java tutorials.  Your `DataRetrieve` class doesn't provide any way to get any data within it.  It executes a query in the constructor, but doesn't store the results anywhere outside the scope of that constructor.  Nor does it have any other methods for accessing such stored data.

Comment: Check out the answer from Frans in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903206/enabling-mysql-general-query-log-with-jdbc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a `ResultSet`.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from contacts");
```

Then you can iterate over ResultSet, and get the rows.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); //gets the first column's rows.
}
```

To get all the column's datas:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (rs.next()) {
    for(int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++)
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you want to print the database information from `MainProgram` calls, you can return the `ResultSet` and iterate over it in your main method.

In this case you should create a method in `MainProgram`.

```
class DataRetrieve {

    DataRetrieve() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phonebook", "root", "1234");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from contacts");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
          return rs;
    }
private ResultSet rs = null;
}
```

And in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataRetrieve dr = new DataRetrieve();
        //here i want to print that table rows into Console using this
        System.out.println(); // How do you print here that table rows?

        ResultSet rs = dr.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); //gets the first column's rows.
        }
}
```

Comment: Small Issue Identified: The for loop should be changed from: for(int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++) to for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) This will allow the last column from the db query to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
class DataRetrieve {

    DataRetrieve() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phonebook", "root", "1234");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from contacts");
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataRetrieve dr = new DataRetrieve();
        //here i want to print that table rows into Console using this
        System.out.println(); // How do you print here that table rows ?
    }
}
```

Well I have caught the rows returned from database in ResultSet instance. You can use `getInt(xxx)`, `getString(xxx)` and etc to get the related values and then to print them.

Comment: It's better to show full example with printing out values in `MainProgram.main`

Answer (score 1):

One basic fault you did is opened the connection **but never closed** it. Its not a good practice you should always close it for releasing the resources.

In your code first `st.executeQuery("select * from contacts");` will return a `ResultSet` object what you need to do is just iterate the `ResultSet` and get the rows.

```
DataRetrieve() {
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("yourUrl", "userName", "password");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("select * from contacts");
    while(resultSet.next())
        {
        String columnName1= rs.getString("nameOfColumn1");
        int columnName2= rs.getInt("nameOfColumn2");
        float columnName3= rs.getFloat("nameOfColumn3");
        System.out.println(columnName1+"\t"+ columnName2+"\t"+ columnName3);
      }
  }
}
catch(SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
   //dont forget the closing statements
 }
```