# I got an Error in Batch Insertion using Hibernate "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table "" when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, batch-insert

I get below mentioned stack trace when inserting data through Batch Insert using Hibernate (I set batch Size initially 6)

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        next value for id_seq_gen
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_fresh_base
        (ASM_NUMBER, BRAND , CIRCLE_TEAM, CIRCLE_TEAM1, CIRCLE_TEAM2, CIRCLE_TEAM3, DIST_Number, DSE_MOB_NO, RETAILER_NUMBER, TSM_NUMBER, UB_COUNT, ZM_NUMBER, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_fresh_base
        (ASM_NUMBER, BRAND , CIRCLE_TEAM, CIRCLE_TEAM1, CIRCLE_TEAM2, CIRCLE_TEAM3, DIST_Number, DSE_MOB_NO, RETAILER_NUMBER, TSM_NUMBER, UB_COUNT, ZM_NUMBER, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_fresh_base
        (ASM_NUMBER, BRAND , CIRCLE_TEAM, CIRCLE_TEAM1, CIRCLE_TEAM2, CIRCLE_TEAM3, DIST_Number, DSE_MOB_NO, RETAILER_NUMBER, TSM_NUMBER, UB_COUNT, ZM_NUMBER, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_fresh_base
        (ASM_NUMBER, BRAND , CIRCLE_TEAM, CIRCLE_TEAM1, CIRCLE_TEAM2, CIRCLE_TEAM3, DIST_Number, DSE_MOB_NO, RETAILER_NUMBER, TSM_NUMBER, UB_COUNT, ZM_NUMBER, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_fresh_base
        (ASM_NUMBER, BRAND , CIRCLE_TEAM, CIRCLE_TEAM1, CIRCLE_TEAM2, CIRCLE_TEAM3, DIST_Number, DSE_MOB_NO, RETAILER_NUMBER, TSM_NUMBER, UB_COUNT, ZM_NUMBER, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_fresh_base
        (ASM_NUMBER, BRAND , CIRCLE_TEAM, CIRCLE_TEAM1, CIRCLE_TEAM2, CIRCLE_TEAM3, DIST_Number, DSE_MOB_NO, RETAILER_NUMBER, TSM_NUMBER, UB_COUNT, ZM_NUMBER, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute batch
vodabaseupload - 2020-01-09 14:56:06,037 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -
                Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_fresh_base' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
vodabaseupload - 2020-01-09 14:56:06,039 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.j.batch.internal.BatchingBatch -
                HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.addToBatch(BatchingBatch.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at com.spice.vodabaseupload.dao.impl.BaseUploadDaoImpl.upload(BaseUploadDaoImpl.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.upload(Unknown Source)
    at com.spice.vodabaseupload.controller.LoginController.upload(LoginController.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_fresh_base' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1824)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:127)
    ... 65 more
vodabaseupload - 2020-01-09 14:56:06,080 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.s.v.controller.LoginController -
                final resp is [null]
```

Here is my Entity Class **BaseUploadEntity.java**

```
package com.spice.vodabaseupload.beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_fresh_base")
public class BaseUploadEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "id_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_gen",sequenceName = "id_seq_gen")
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="RETAILER_NUMBER")
    private String RETAILERNUMBER;

    @Column(name="DSE_MOB_NO")
    private String DSE_MOB_NO;

    @Column(name="DIST_Number")
    private String DIST_Number;

    @Column(name="TSM_NUMBER")
    private String TSM_NUMBER;

    @Column(name="ASM_NUMBER")
    private String ASM_NUMBER;

    @Column(name="ZM_NUMBER")
    private String ZM_NUMBER;


    @Column(name="CIRCLE_TEAM")
    private String CIRCLE_TEAM;

    @Column(name="CIRCLE_TEAM1")
    private String CIRCLE_TEAM1;

    @Column(name="CIRCLE_TEAM2")
    private String CIRCLE_TEAM2;

    @Column(name="CIRCLE_TEAM3")
    private String CIRCLE_TEAM3;

    @Column(name="BRAND ")
    private String Brand;

    @Column(name="UB_COUNT")
    private String UB_Count;

   //Here are getters and Setters//


}
```

Here is the **Application.properties** file

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url = jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=demo
jdbc.username = bgm
jdbc.password = bgm
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 6
hibernate.order_inserts = true
```

**Creating SessionFactory with JavaConfig** like this

```
package com.spice.vodabaseupload.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.spice.vodabaseupload.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class ProjectConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.spice.vodabaseupload.beans" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
        properties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }   
}
```

Here is my **BaseUploadDaoImpl.class**

```
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(baseFileToCreate);
            Workbook workbook = getRelevantWorkbook(inputStream, baseFileToCreate.toString());

            Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

            int count = 0;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                BaseUploadEntity entity = new BaseUploadEntity();
                count++;
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setRETAILERNUMBER(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setRETAILERNUMBER(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }

                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setDSE_MOB_NO(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setDSE_MOB_NO(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setDIST_Number(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setDIST_Number(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 3) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setTSM_NUMBER(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setTSM_NUMBER(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 4) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setASM_NUMBER(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setASM_NUMBER(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 5) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setZM_NUMBER(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setZM_NUMBER(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 6) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 7) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM1(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM1(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 8) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM2(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM2(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 9) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM3(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setCIRCLE_TEAM3(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 10) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setBrand(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setBrand(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }

                        else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 11) {
                            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                                entity.setUB_Count(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            }

                            else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                                entity.setUB_Count(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    session.save(entity);
                    if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                        LOGGER.info("Inserting " + count + " Record");
                        session.flush();
                        session.clear();
                    }   
                }
            inputStream.close();
```

**However without Batch Insertion the code is working fine**

Comment: Why is your column set to use sequence based value generation, while apparently you're using identity columns?

Comment: This may be relevant for [batch insert and identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27732138/4808122)

Comment: Actually there was a mistake in the code so the issue has resolved now.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've read somewhere that Identity Type ID Generation has not supported Batch Insertion in Hibernate, that's why I've used Sequence Generator

Comment: @n-kit How did you resolve this error?