# org.hibernate.Session.save() triggering DB insert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got the problem that my entity is inserted into the db without any "flush" being called,
Maybe someone has an idea under which circumstances a session.save immediately triggers db insert?

I think the only to interesting parts of my object which I would like to save (but not persist(!)) is

```
  @javax.persistence.Id
  @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @javax.persistence.Column(name = "EM_id")
  private Long     id;

  @javax.persistence.Version
  @javax.persistence.Column(name = "version")
  private int      version;
```

Comment: When you save but don't persist what is the output?

Comment: The Object gets inserted into the DB, (i just create the object, and then I call session.save(object), nothing else)

Comment: What do you expect `save()` to do? `save()` is used to write data into the database https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/difference-hibernate-save-vs-persist-and-saveOrUpdate.html

Comment: Up to now we've used hibernate with those xyz.hbm.xml files, now I've added a class which uses hibernate with annotations, objects of this annotation-using-class are now inserted to the DB, other objects (from classes which are configured via hbm.xml files) are only saved when I call "persist" (is there a way to configure the behaviour of "save"?)

Comment: See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697810/hibernate-disabled-insert-batching-when-using-an-identity-identifier-generator) and the answer by @vlad-mihalcea.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the FlushMode of all our sessions is set to     FlushMode.MANUAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you handling the transactions manually? If you are, you should start the transaction before calling `save()`. Commit the transaction after calling `save()`. I believe not starting the transaction might have been causing this.

If above is not the case, the saving without `flush()` is happening because of default hibernate flush mode being `AUTO`. Try changing it to `COMMIT`.