# Spring Boot Appllication. Batch doesn't work in JpaRepository.saveAll method

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is spring boot application with configuration:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 20
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        generate_statistics: true
        format_sql: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
        default_schema: ${SCHEMA}
```

I use JpaRepository.saveAll method for inserting new data into DB.
But I don't see that batching working.

There is logs:

```
Session Metrics {
    1501300 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    13234500 nanoseconds spent preparing 1013 JDBC statements;
    1636949500 nanoseconds spent executing 1013 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    12971600 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1012 entities and 0 collections);
    4901200 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 4 entities and 4 collections)
}
```

Versions:

1. spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE
2. postgresql-42.2.12

Comment: Please check if this helps `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697810/hibernate-disabled-insert-batching-when-using-an-identity-identifier-generator/27732138`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batch doesn't work with GenerationType.IDENTITY

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Need to use sequence.

Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "row_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "row_generator", sequenceName = "db_generator", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago.
I simply call save(...) one by one for all the entities from inside a transaction now, and it works as expected.

Comment: Yep, but there are diferent statements. Batch is one statement with many operations.

Comment: Hibernate will merge the separated save commands to batches.