# GenerationType.IDENTITY with transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use GenerationType.IDENTITY with Transaction in Hibernate/Spring data?

I have an existing database, with an identity column in all tables. So, I have to use GenerationType.IDENTITY for it. But, when I create a new entity instance and change its state to managed with someRepository.save(...) method, the persistence provider can't acquire a new ID for that entity, because it must happen on flush time, at the end of the transaction.

If I create one entity, all works as expected. After save(), the entity goes to the managed state, the id is changed from NULL to 0 (zero), and at the flush time, the new ID for the row is generated by the database.

But what if we create two instances of the same entity class inside one transaction? The exception will be thrown, and this is justly because we have two different objects with same ID = 0. So, is there a way to deal with it without change strategy from IDENTITY to something else?

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    ...
}

@Transactional
public void brokenCode() {
    Customer one = new Customer();
    Customer two = new Customer();
    someRepository.save(one);
    someRepository.save(two); <--- org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] 
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT  [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) 
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
                , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
                , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
                , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
                , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
                , OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [DATA]
)
```

**UPD!**

The reason is the table has "trigger instead of insert". In that trigger some fields are calculated based on other fields. And the identity doesn't return to Hibernate.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Customer] on [dbo].[Customer]
instead of insert
as
if @@rowcount = 0 return

set nocount on
Set dateformat dmy

Insert into dbo.Customer
(f1, f2, ....)
Select 
       I.f1,
       isnull(f2,newid()),
       ...
from Inserted I
```

So. Is there a way to somehow return identity to Hibernate from that trigger?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to inject a reference to the JPA `EntityManager` and call `flush()` on it in between saving the two entities. I'm not positive that will resolve the identity conflict, but it might.

Comment: @Andrei, what DB are you on? would you mind providing corresponding table DDL?

Comment: Injecting EntityManager and flush() doesn't help. Database will generate new ID's only on transaction end. I use the MSSQL.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT  [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) 
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
                , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
                , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
                , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
                , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
                , OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [DATA]
)

Comment: This might be the answer for your question, it basically discard the possibility what you want to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697810/why-does-hibernate-disable-insert-batching-when-using-an-identity-identifier-gen

Comment: @Vikram, thanks, But in the statement log I can see the insert, so insert not batched. But the zero identifier is returned from DB and I got an exception. Maybe I have to tune something in application.properties?

Comment: The database should not be generating new IDs only when the transaction ends - it must generate IDs after each insert statement, and your JPA provider will have to check with the database after each insert statement to determine what that ID was: a huge performance weakness of identity when compared to sequences or other strategies that allow pre-allocation. But it does work; if you are getting 0 or other issues, show the exception and SQL logged too. I'm not a DBA who understands the settings you've used on your table, but try simplifying it

Comment: @Andrei did you try removing Transactional annotation from your brokenCode method? i think it should work, since save method is also Transactional method and default propagation for Transactional is REQUIRED which mean same transaction (declared by brokenCode method ) will be used for two consecutive save method calls, let me know if it works

Comment: Seems like my problem in one concrete table, guys, need time to research more. Thanks you all, especially @Vikram. Love you! Tomorrow i will write the update for this topic!

Comment: updated, the reason is - trigger