Spring + Hibernate batch inserts doesnt work
I'm setting properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true

adding to 1 of 20 entity
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

other entities  have
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

but there is no batch inserts
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getJdbcBatchSize() returns null
I'm thinking that entities with IDENTITY strategy blocking batch inserts for entity with SEQUENCE strategy.
How can i avoid this without changing Id generation strategy for ALL entities?
I was trying to change jdbBatchSize in entityManager in debug mode and batch insert works well for my entity with SEQUENCE strategy

Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an identity identifier generator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697810/why-does-hibernate-disable-insert-batching-when-using-an-identity-identifier-gen

As far as I know if You have Integer or Long ids, You cannot make batch insert by using GenerationType.IDENTITY because Hibernate needs to know which predefined sequence it exactly will use during batch inserts. That's why it needs GenerationType.SEQUENCE. There is another way to achive this problem. If you use Integer or Long id, you can change them as UUID. Then, you dont have to change the GenerationType.
