# How to Monitor the application flow

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I would like to monitor the Java application created which has UI being rendered in JSP, containing Servlets and Tomcat Server and DB and mysql.

I would like to monitor the flow at each level - to check the performance at each level (for each request and response).

PS: I do not want to modify my application code. I want to monitor it without accessing or modifying the code. Access it only using port no via separate application. No Third party tools.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Comment: https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html

Comment: https://websistent.com/linux-iptables-log-everything/

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Eclipse has a profiler which might help in checking performance

Comment: Postgres: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/logging.html MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903206/enabling-mysql-general-query-log-with-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

There are **multiple** ways to monitor performance, but below is **one of simplest ways.**

1.Add logger.info() into your code wherever needed.

2.Add **timestamp** to each line of log messages into **console** as below.

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
```

Now, each log line contains the timestamp when it is printed,

by reading this log lines you can easily find which code block (between log lines) is taking more time.

Comment: I do not want to modify my application code. I want to monitor it without accessing or modifying the code. Access it only using port no. No Third party tools.